# env argument does not work in system2?

Tags: r

I am trying to run a command using `system2` and to set an environment variable using the `env` argument, but it appears not to be set. I'm on Linux so this should work [in the helpfile it mentions that `env` sometimes doesn't work in Windows].

Does anyone know how to set environment variables in `system32`?

E.g.

```
system2('echo', args='foobar')
# foobar # as expected
system2('echo', args='$X', env="X=foobar")
#   # <-- nothing is printed. as if I had just done `echo`
# I expect to see 'foobar' echoed.

# pretty sure the above environment specification is right, but just in case
system2('echo', args='$X', env=c(X='foobar'))
# sh: 1: foobar: not found

# just to show it can work
system('X=foobar; echo $X')
# foobar
```

I will just use `system` as a workaround for now, but the `system` helpfile keeps going on about how I should be using `system2`.
(If this is a bug, where do I file it?)

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu precise (12.04.5 LTS)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_AU.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_AU.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_AU.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_AU.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_AU.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_AU.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_AU.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: How about `system2("echo", args="$X", env=c("X=foobar;"))`? The command that goes to the shell is just `paste(c(env, shQuote(command), args), collapse = " ")`.

Comment: Yes! Thanks! The helpfile just says "character vector of `name=value` strings" so I assumed the semicolon would not be necessary. Please post as an answer, I couldn't find any other questions related to this.

Comment: A bit hesitant about this answer though, since I'm not sure why `X=foobar echo $X` doesn't work (from either `system` or `system2`). Also not sure this is the way the `env` argument is supposed to be used. Perhaps someone more in the know can enlighten...

Comment: I think it's because that syntax doesn't work in `sh` (which I guess `system` uses instead of `bash`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the command that goes to the shell is just `paste(c(env, shQuote(command), args), collapse = " ")`, you can do:

```
system2("echo", args = "$X", env = c("X=foobar;"))
```

Comment: Note for anyone else who hits their head on the wall for a day on this: I tried to pass my env variables as *named* vector elements (`X = "foobar"`) rather than having the variable names _in_ the element value (`"X=foobar"`) and was getting a lot of `exec format error` be cause my first env variable was interpreted as the executable I wanted to run.

Comment: Another example of the poor base R doc which defines param `env` as: `character vector of name=value strings to set environment variables.`

This could easily be misinterpreted as "named character vector of key = value pairs", i.e. `c(ENVVAR = "blabla")`. 